# What Is Wrong With This authentication Code?

Tags: java, swing

Please Guys i've been on this all day trying to get my managerCorner GUI to execute based on this authentication. I have used correct values, i.e Values from my database to check if the managerLogin() method will grant me access to the managerCorner GUI interface, but it hasnt worked. There's a LoginInterface class with a form that handles user authentications. I have tried login in with the correct values but the managerCorner GUI class within th if(rset.next())... doesn't called, no exceptions or errors are flagged off! Why is this so?

```
public void managerLogin(int id, String usn, String pwd) {
try {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/    phoneShopSystem","aknessy", dbLogin.db());
    String query = "SELECT managerID, managerUsername, managerPwd"
    + "FROM `manager` WHERE managerID = ? AND managerUsername = ? AND managerPwd = ?";
    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    int i = rset.getInt(1);
    String u = rset.getString(2);
    String p = rset.getString(3);

    rset = pst.executeQuery();
    if(rset.next()){
        if((i == id) && (u.equals(usn)) && (p.equals(pwd))){
            new managerCorner();
            managerCorner.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

            }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The User: "+ usn +" With ID "+ id + " \n"
            + "Does Not Exist!", "\nLogin Failed!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        }
        rset.close();
        con.close();
        }catch(SQLException sql){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sql.getMessage(),"SQL   ERROR!!!",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Please format your code. This code is gonna look pretty messy to the next programmer who gives you a performance review.

Comment: Where do you set your query statement parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these two lines:

```
new managerCorner();
managerCorner.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

In all likelyhood, this is not what you wanted to do. It won't even compile. You have a better chance of being correct if you write this:

```
corner = new managerCorner();
corner.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

I'm not entirely sure that this will work, but I don't have enough information to be sure about it.

---

As Morrison Chang pointed out, there is also no code to set the parameters for the `PreparedStatement`. Maybe that is also a problem?